# Using Abstract Base Class with (non-virtual) Template Method

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic-cast

I've recently run across code in our product using a technique I haven't seen before. I'm looking for references to see if this is an established technique (I wouldn't go so far as to call it a pattern), and if so, what are the understood risks and benefits. Please note that for business reasons, we cannot use C++11 constructs.

The example code below illustrates one use of the technique. We have two adapters derived from an abstract base class, which defines the common API to be accessed by clients.

One client decides it needs to expose the adapted class. Just for this simple example, the client uses a type tag switch statement to discover the type.

To implement, the author defines the abstract base class. In it, he has a nested class template, which contains a pure virtual getter returning pointer to type T. He also has a non-virtual, templated method which gets instantiated for each type needed (best to consult the example below).

Adapters derive from both the abstract base class, and it's nested template class. Then they implement the virtual getter.

Clients will know the type of the adapted class, and can call the non-virtual templated base class method with the appropriate type. This in turn calls the adapter class' template method. The main aim here seems to be freeing the client from using dynamic_cast<>(), or needing to define templates themselves.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum ObjectProxyType {
  SimpleProxy,
  CompoundProxy
};

class ObjectProxyIfc
{
protected:
   ObjectProxyIfc() {}

public:
   virtual ~ObjectProxyIfc() {}

   virtual ObjectProxyType type() const = 0;

   virtual std::string name() = 0;
   // adapter method (example)

   template<class T>
   class ProxyGetterIfc
   {
   public:
      virtual const T* get() const = 0;
   };

   template <typename T>
   const T* get() const
   {
      // this templated method is non-virtual, and should not be
      // overridden/shadowed by derived classes. Adapters will derive
      // from ObjectProxyIfc *and*
      // ObjectProxyIfc::ProxyGetterIfc<type-to-be-wrapped>, and then
      // implement the wrapped virtual method, called here.
      //
      ProxyGetterIfc<T> *getter = dynamic_cast<ProxyGetterIfc<T> *>(const_cast<ObjectProxyIfc *>(this));
      return getter ? getter->get() : 0;
   }
};

class SimpleObject
{
public:
   SimpleObject() {};
   ~SimpleObject() {};

   std::string objName() const { return "SimpleObject"; }
};

class SimpleObjectProxy : public ObjectProxyIfc,
                         public ObjectProxyIfc::ProxyGetterIfc<SimpleObject> 
{
public:
   SimpleObjectProxy(SimpleObject *obj) : obj_(obj) {};
   ~SimpleObjectProxy() {};

   virtual ObjectProxyType type() const { return SimpleProxy; }

   virtual std::string name()
   {
      // adapter for wrapped object
      return obj_->objName();
   }

   virtual const SimpleObject *get() const {
     return obj_;
   } 

private:
   SimpleObject  *obj_;
};

ObjectProxyIfc *oPI()
{
   return new SimpleObjectProxy(new SimpleObject());
}

class CompoundObject
{
public:
   CompoundObject(const std::string &annotation) : annotation_(annotation) {};
   ~CompoundObject() {};

   std::string objName() const { return "CompoundObject"; }

   std::string annotation() const
   {
      // No adapter method is available for this item!
      return annotation_;
   }

private:
   std::string annotation_;
};

class CompoundObjectProxy : public ObjectProxyIfc,
                            public ObjectProxyIfc::ProxyGetterIfc<CompoundObject *>
{
public:
   CompoundObjectProxy(CompoundObject **objs) : objs_(objs) {};
   ~CompoundObjectProxy() {};

   virtual ObjectProxyType type() const { return CompoundProxy; }

   virtual std::string name()
   {
      // adapter for wrapped object
      return objs_[0]->objName();
   }

   virtual CompoundObject *const *get() const {
      return const_cast< CompoundObject *const *>(objs_);
   }

private:
   CompoundObject  **objs_;
};

ObjectProxyIfc *oPI2()
{
   CompoundObject *so = new CompoundObject("non-shared payload");
   CompoundObject **sop = new (CompoundObject *);
   *sop = so;
   return new CompoundObjectProxy(sop);
}

void handleObj(ObjectProxyIfc *iObj)
{
   switch (iObj->type())
   {
      case SimpleProxy: {
         const SimpleObject *anObj = iObj->get<SimpleObject>();
         std::cout << "Handling " << anObj->objName() << std::endl;
      } break;
      case CompoundProxy: {
         CompoundObject *const *objs = iObj->get<CompoundObject *>();
         const CompoundObject *anObj = *objs;
         std::cout << "Handling " << anObj->objName() << "; " << anObj->annotation() << std::endl;
      } break;
   }
}

int main()
{
   // common, adapted methods can be accessed from the base class for
   // adapters, re: name()
   //
   ObjectProxyIfc *ptrOne = oPI();
   std::cout << "First object is " << ptrOne->name() << std::endl;

   // rarely, the client may need access to the data/methods in the
   // wrapped object, which have no counterpart in the common subset
   // implemented by the adapter. For this we go directly to the
   // wrapped object.
   //
   handleObj(ptrOne);

   ObjectProxyIfc *ptrTwo = oPI2();
   std::cout << "Second object is " << ptrTwo->name() << std::endl;
   handleObj(ptrTwo);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: "A class has a member function template that encapsulates a dynamic cast, someone calls it". Don't see much of a technique here. What makes it unusual?

Comment: n.m.: Unusual may not be the right word here. I'm trying to suss out the value of doing it this way over direct use of dynamic_cast<>(). And the forwarding (from the abstract base class' non-virtual method to the virtual derived method) seems to be part and parcel of the 'usage' (if you prefer that word over 'technique').

Comment: Calling a virtual function from a non-virtual wrapper is standard. See e.g. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface

Comment: Thank you, n.m., references like this are what I was after. I've heard of the Template Method Pattern before, but ironically have never seen it accomplished with C++ templates before. And the use here is not a typical goal of the Template Method Pattern. Perhaps that clouded my recall.

Comment: You are right, this is not a real template method in the GoF-sense, but the non-virtual interface idiom is useful for any kind of method.